# bazel large / enormous test targets in bazel and parallelism

Tags: bazel

I have a repository with 5-6 large tests that takes longer time and consume a lot of resources. I have issue with running bazel locally because those tests run in parallel with other actions.

Issues like:

```
JUnit4 Test Runner
takeStaticsFromRepo=false
Evaluating Ruby ERB methods ...Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x000000077f280000, 91750400, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 91750400 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
```

I know that without remote execution and without supplying the `--jobs=x` flag, bazel would run actions in parallel according to the number of cores.

Obviously - my "`large`+" targets cannot run in parallel like "`medium`-"  ones - they need more resources. The problem described above happens occasionally.

Is there a way to do better throttling?
Do some heuristic about memory consumption per test size and have dynamic number of actions in parallel.

---

One solution would be to add the tag `exclusive` to the `large` tests - but that would kill any parallelism.

---

- I'm using the current latest release (`0.15.2`) on linux
- I would really prefer not to split bazel invocation to multiple invocations with test_size_filter.

Comment: If you haven't tried these it might be worth a shot, though I suspect they would only work for the build step and not the test: --ram_utilization_factor or --local_resources
https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html